# Como retornar um objeto de um banco noSQL(MongoDb)?

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi, mongodb, nosql, object-pascal

Atualmente tenho alguns objetos em um banco de dados MongoDB. A estrutura encontra-se da seguinte forma.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55cb9c666c522cafdb053a68"),
    "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                [
                    -73.93383000695911,
                    40.81949109558767
                ],
                ...
            ]
        ]
    },
    "name" : "Central Harlem North-Polo Grounds"
}
```

Usando o delphi eu consigo obter um objeto inteiro e remover o "_id", ou seja, meu retorno é um Json com o "Geometry" e o "Name". Segue o código do Delphi.

```
   collection := FMongoConn.Databases['DataBase'].GetCollection('collec');

   mqry := TMongoQuery.Create(collection.Env);
   mqry := mqry.Project('{_id: false}').&End;  //Aqui eu removo o _id que não preciso

   Cursor := collection.Find(mqry);

   while Cursor.Next do
      Cursor.Doc.AsJSON  //Json de cada documento
```

Estou tentando obter somente o objeto "geometry" e retornar ele para o Json, tem como fazer isso usando os procedimentos do driver do Delphi(FireDac) ou através do find do Mongo?

O retorno pretentido seria somente esse

```
"geometry" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                [
                    -73.93383000695911,
                    40.81949109558767
                ],
                ...
            ]
        ]
    }
```

Através do próprio MongoDB, tem como trazer somente um objeto inteiro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a uses "System.JSON".

Se "Cursor.Doc.AsJSON" for um objeto TJSONObject:

```
var
  geometry: TJSONObject;
begin
  geometry := Cursor.Doc.AsJSON.GetValue('geometry') as TJSONObject;
  Memo1.Text := geometry.ToString;
end;
```

Se "Cursor.Doc.AsJSON" for uma string:

```
var
  j, geometry : TJSONObject;
begin
  j := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Cursor.Doc.AsJSON), 0) as TJSONObject;
  geometry := j.GetValue('geometry') as TJSONObject;
  Memo1.Text := geometry.ToString;
end;
```

Comment: Era exatamente disso que eu precisava, muito obrigado, Marcio!